# Getting Links from a HTML Page

Tags: html, windows, vbscript, hyperlink

I want to automate a Process at work. I have a web page which will have some 20-30 Links which starts with the specific words as follows.

```
abc1234
abc5142
abc9862
abc3621
```

Each of these lines are basically Links. Clicking on which I will get one more browser which will have the IP.

Now I want to know the IP behind each machine name (ex: abc6901) and I want to connect to those machines using VNC viewer.

```vb
Dim Browser, strOut
Set Browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With Browser
  .Visible = False
  .Navigate "http://anees.amoeba.co.in/table.html"
  'Wait for Browser
  Do While .Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
  Loop
End With
```

But when I tried to do the same, I failed to get the link details from the HTML page, using the .vbs script file. I worked on getting the same and found I'm stuck with the methods `document.getElementById` and some other methods which will get the link details.

Also, I don't know how to get the info of the node where these Links are present on the web page. For better understanding, I will be pasting my screen shot of my page from the application.

[image]

Comment: Nothing we can do to help you without knowing the structure of your web page. What does the source look like? How is the task list created? On the server side? On the client side via JavaScript? On the client side via a Java applet? Some other plugin?

Comment: Yeah, my few more research told me like -- its an Adobe Flash Player applet. The Structure which u asked for -- where do i get it ??

Comment: I don't think you can extract content from a Flash page.

Comment: Oh... But how i got to know this is like -- on the Right Click on the Link which i told, and if u go to Settings -- it says -- "Adobe Flash Player Settings". is this the right of getting to know ??

Comment: The Flash applet may have clickable links, but that doesn't necessarily mean there's an API to extract them.

Comment: Right click your page and choose View Source. Search for your links `abc1234` and copy surrounding code and update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Explorer 5 Power Toys include a List Links program.

Create following htm page `C:\Windows\WEB\urllist.htm`

```
<script language=javascript defer>
var str = new String ("toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=0, left=0, width=400, height=");

str = str + (screen.height - 100);

//alert (screen.height);

var dlProgress = window.open ("", "linkdownloader", str);

dlProgress.document.open();
dlProgress.document.writeln ("<html>");
dlProgress.document.writeln ("<head>");
dlProgress.document.writeln ("<title>Links list</title>");
dlProgress.document.writeln ("</head>");
dlProgress.document.writeln ("<body topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0 bottommargin=0>");
dlProgress.document.writeln ("<font style=\"font:   8pt Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif; line-height:18pt;\">");
dlProgress.document.writeln ("<script language=javascript>function navigateClose(str){if (document.my_parent != null){document.my_parent.location.href=str;window.close();}else{alert(\"Please wait until the list has populated.\");}}<\/script>");

dlProgress.document.writeln ("&nbsp;List of all links in <b>" + external.menuArguments.document.title + "</b>:<ol>");
var links = external.menuArguments.document.links;
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
    if ( links(i).innerText != "" && links(i).innerText != " ")
    {
        dlProgress.document.writeln ("<li><A HREF='javascript:navigateClose(\"" + links(i).href + "\")' TITLE=" + links(i).href + ">" + links(i).innerText + "</a><BR>");
    }
    else
    {
        dlProgress.document.writeln ("<li><A HREF='javascript:navigateClose(\"" + links(i).href + "\")'>" + links(i).href + "</a><BR>");
    }
}
dlProgress.document.writeln ("</ol><center><a href='javascript:window.close()' style=\"color:#FF0000;text-decoration:none\">close</a></center><BR></body>");
dlProgress.document.writeln ("</font></html>");
dlProgress.document.close();

dlProgress.document.my_parent = external.menuArguments;
</script>
```

To install run this reg file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\&Links List]
@="C:\\Windows\\WEB\\urllist.htm"
"contexts"=hex:01
```

To use right click page and choose Links List.